# python printing vectors in different forms

Tags: python, function, if-statement, module, mapping

Write a program called ‘vectormath.py’ to do basic vector calculations in 3 dimensions:
addition, dot product and normalization.

There's an error on my mapping function.

sample input:

```
Enter vector A:

1 3 2

Enter vector B:

2 3 0
```

sample output

```
A+B = [3, 6, 2]

A.B = 11

|A| = 3.74

|B| = 3.61
```

Code:

```
import math
def addition(a,b):
    return[a[0]+b[0] , a[1] + b[1] , a[2] + b[2]]

def  Dotproduct(a , b):
    return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]

def norm(a):
    square = a[0]**2 + a[1]**2 + a[2]**2
    return math.sqrt(square)

def main():
    vector_A = input("Enter vector A:\n").split(" ")
    vector_A = map(int,vector_A)
    vector_B = input("Enter vector B:\n").split(" ")
    vector_B = map(int, vector_B)
    
    print(addition(vector_A,vector_B))
    print(addition(vector_A,vector_B))
    print(norm(vector_A))
    print(norm(vector_B))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`vector_A = map(int,vector_A)` with  `vector_A = list(map(int, vector_A))`

and

`vector_B = map(int,vector_B)` with  `vector_B = list(map(int, vector_B))`

Here `map(int, vector_A)` returns a map object which is an iterator.

`list()` takes the iterator and returns a list which you require in your code for further vector calculation.

As of now, you are passing `map object` to functions `addition, Dotproduct and norm`, which actually should be a list for the calculations defined.

Above changes converts the map object to list.